# Notification Centre preferences are empty

Tags: macos, notifications

I'm not receiving any notifications for any apps on my Mac running Sierra. I'm pretty sure the screenshot of my notification centre preferences below is illustrating the problem, i.e. there's nothing there.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same thing after trying to work out why my iMessages notifications aren't appearing. No idea how to fix it though.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this problem and fixed it by doing an NVRAM reset. Switch off computer and restart. Immediately press and hold Command and Alt/Option and the P and R keys. When you hear the second start up chime (about 30 seconds later) release the keys. Your Notifications preferences should be fully populated again by all the apps that use it.